# Issue with Vector Mimicking Stack Behavior in R Programming Language

Tags: r, vector, data-structures

I have two functions in R one that is working and finds if a number is prime recursively, and the other which doesn't work that has said function inside. The second function is supposed to tell if a number is prime and then add it to a vector but I keep getting an error that I have reached my C memory limit. I believe that I have programmed incorrectly the second function, and would like some help to find the error in the second function.

Function One:

```
find_prime <- function(a,i=2){
  if(a == i)
    return(T)
  else if(a %% i == 0)
    return(F)
  return(find_prime(a,i = i + 1))
}
```

Function `find_prime` works as desired; however, `ls_vec_prime` does not work as desired.

Function Two:

```
ls_vec_prime <- function(vec){
  l <- vector()
  while(length(vec)!= 0){
  if(find_prime(vec[1]) == T){
    l <- c(vec[1],l)
    
  }
  vec <- vec[-1]
  }
  print(vec)
return(l)
}
```

I would like to keep the method of using a while loop to solve this problem and was wondering what exactly is wrong in my implementation.

This is my setup:

```
find_prime <- function(a,i=2){
  if(a == i)
    return(T)
  else if(a %% i == 0)
    return(F)
  return(find_prime(a,i = i + 1))
}
ls_vec_prime <- function(vec){
  l <- vector()
  while(length(vec)!= 0){
  if(find_prime(vec[1]) == T){
    l <- c(vec[1],l)
  }
  vec <- vec[-1]
  }
return(l)
}
vec_1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
ls_vec_prime(vec_1)
```

## Temporary Fix

```
find_prime <- function(a,i=2){
  if(a == 1)
    return("1 is not Prime")
  if(a == i)
    return(T)
  else if(a %% i == 0)
    return(F)
  return(find_prime(a,i = i + 1))
}
find_prime(3)
ls_vec_prime <- function(vec){
  l <- vector()
  while(length(vec)!= 0){
  if(find_prime(vec[1]) == T){
    l <- c(vec[1],l)
  }
  vec = vec[-1]
  }
  return(l)
}
ls_vec_prime(vec_1)
```

For the setup vector I now get:

```
[1] 3 2
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error. How exactly are you calling `ls_vec_prime`? Just a warning that appending values one at a time and deleting them one at a time in R will be very slow for large collections due to memory reallocations. If you are going to use a while loop, it would be much better to preallocate the result vector and iterate by index to populate it.

Comment: @MrFlick I added how I am setting it up.

Comment: The same error occurs if you just run `find_prime(1)`. It doesn't really have to do with vectorization. You just need to be more careful during the recursion.

Comment: I just realized my mistake 1 is not a prime number, 2 is the smallest prime number!!!!!